# Mockito and Powermock testing in android

Tags: android, mockito, powermock

How to mock static constructor with coordinator layout and context  as params.

```
public RequestHandler()
{         
    this.client = new AsyncHttpClient();
}
public static RequestHandler getInstance( CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout,Context context)
{
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new RequestHandler ();
    }
    instance.coordinatorLayout = coordinatorLayout;    
    instance.context=context;       
    notificationProvider = new NotificationProvider (coordinatorLayout);     
    instance.myUserSessionManager=new MyUserSessionManager (context);     
    return instance;
}
```

I get

> Unable to mock the construction of the RequestHandler object
>   cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't mock static methods.  You can only mock instance methods of Java objects that are declared non-final.

Comment: Can't I use Power mock to create object calling the constructor?  PowerMockito.when(RequestHandler.getInstance(coordinatorLayout,getSystemContext())).thenReturn(handler);

Comment: If this is something you tried and expect to work, but didn't work, that is be something you should mention in the question.

Comment: Ok then, how can I use Power mock to create object invoke the constructor of this type?

Comment: Why don't you reformulate a new question asking this, along with exactly what you have tried and what didn't work as expected.  (Note that there are tutorials on this if you search for them.)

Comment: Thank you ..I will reformulate and post . I have search lot but but didn't got a clue pending my work for a week.